# How to sequence GraphQL queries to output data dependent from each other?

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, apollo, api-gateway

I have two microservices **ms1** and **ms2** that output different types of data each time an API gateway built with Apollo GraphQL sends requests through resolvers.

To be specific, the first resolver `getCart(userId: ID!): Cart!` calls **ms1** and it responds it with the following response body:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "8a016af8-5336-4799-b806-73976996aa6f",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "itemId": "9a016af8-5336-4799-b806-73976996aa6f",
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

That is, the `Cart` type, just an object containing an array of items with id and quantity.

The second resolver `getItem(itemId: ID!): Item!` calls **ms2** and it responds it with the following response body:

```json
{
  "itemId": "7a016af8-5336-4b99-b806-73976996aadf",
  "name": "Jack Daniel's Blue Label",
  "price": 29.99
}
```

---

Is there any way to "combine" or sequence these two queries directly from a frontend (e.g. Apollo Sandbox or GraphiQL) in such a way that I get the following response?

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "8a016af8-5336-4799-b806-73976996aa6f",
      "name": "Jack Daniel's - Honey",
      "price": 19.99,
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "itemId": "7a016af8-5336-4799-b806-73976996aa6f",
      "name": "Jack Daniel's - Red Label",
      "price": 29.99,
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In pseudo-graphql I was thinking about something like this:

```
query GetCartInfo($userId: ID!) { 
  getCart(userId: $userId) {
    items {
      itemId => getItem(itemId: $itemId) {
        name
        price
      }
      quantity
    }
  }
}
```

If that's not possible, what would be the best way to achieve this? Create a new resolver in the API gateway? Modify the array from another service in the frontend?

Comment: So `Cart` is defined to have a field `items` of type `[Item!]`? Then just write `items { name price quantity }`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from the client, you need to modify the GraphQL schema and your resolvers.

In your schema you should have a `Cart` type and an `Item` type and also a `CartItem` type to deal with quantities.

```
type Cart {
  id: ID!
  contents: [CartItem]
}

type Item {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  price: Float!
}

type CartItem {
  id: ID!
  quantity: Int!
  item: Item!
}
```

Given this structure, your query:

```
getCart(userId: ID!): Cart!
```

Should be able to be called with:

```
query getUsersCart($userId: ID!) {
  getCart(userId: $userId) {
    cartItem {
      quantity
      item {
        id
        name
        price
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your `getCart` query resolver needs to invokes `ms1` to get the the list of `CartItem`s and then, like @orabis suggests, your `CartItem` type needs a resolver for the `item` field that invokes `ms2`. GraphQL will automatically combine the results of the query resolver with the field resolver.

The response should look like:

```
[
  "cartItem": {
    "quantity": 1,
    item: {
      "id": "8a016af8-5336-4799-b806-73976996aa6f",
      "name": "Jack Daniel's - Honey",
      "price": 19.99
    }
  },
  cartItem: {
    "quantity": 2,
    item: {
      "id": "7a016af8-5336-4799-b806-73976996aa6f",
      "name": "Jack Daniel's - Red Label",
      "price": 29.99
    }
  }
]
```

I should add that if this query is to be done by the user who owns the cart then for security the user's `id` should **not** be a parameter to the query. The user's `id` should be provided by the `context` parameter to the query resolver.

Comment: Thank so much for the answer! Also, the query is meant to be done by the front-end each time the user logs in. It is still recommended to changing this though?

Comment: Yes, just define a query `myCart` with no parameters. Get the user's id from context. Otherwise user A can spoof user B and peek inside someone else's cart.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use GraphQL's field resolvers, which allow defining custom logic to resolve fields in a GraphQL query.

In the API gateway, you can create a new resolver that resolves the items field in the getCart query. Here is a rough example:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getCartInfo: async (_, { userId }) => {
      // Send a request to ms1 to get the cart data
      const cartData = await ms1API.getCart(userId);

      // Send a request to ms2 to get item details For each item
      const itemPromises = cartData.items.map(async (item) => {
        const itemDetails = await ms2API.getItem(item.itemId);
        return {
          itemId: item.itemId,
          name: itemDetails.name,
          price: itemDetails.price,
          quantity: item.quantity,
        };
      });

      const items = await Promise.all(itemPromises);

      return {
        items,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that it is unlikely to solve this solely from the front.  I will definitely take a look to this trick.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to do this not on the client, but on the server by using a Gateway or Federation Router service in front of your microservices that stitches both of these `Item` entities into one and answers your query for `Item` with only one query from the client, but answers from both microservices.

One way of doing that would be Apollo Federation. You can [read up on that here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/).

Comment: This is overkill for this simple situation.

Comment: @MichelFloyd OP describes a microservice setup. This is not a "simple situation".

Comment: I'll assert that it is. A single GraphQL server is perfectly capable of handling multiple microservices. Federation becomes useful when you need to combine results from multiple GraphQL servers.

Comment: I think this solution should be the way to go on the middle term, mostly because implementing this solution should rely on the whole dev team agreement, not just me :( although, thanks so much for the recommendation!

Comment: ps. The federation approach would be correct *if* each microservice was presenting a GraphQL api.